# RxJS: conditional throttling

Tags: rxjs

i want to have a stream that emits while the user is typing. It should emit at most once per second, unless the either the before or the after is an empty input box. In other words, it must always emit immediately if the user types (or pastes) the first character, or if he empties his input. I now have this, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for:

```
        this.chatForm.get('message')
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(
                startWith(this.chatForm.get('message').value),
                pairwise(),
                throttle(([a, b]) => {
                    if (!a || !b) {
                        return timer(0);
                    }

                    return timer(1000);
                }),
                map(([, b]) => b),
                withLatestFrom(this.user$)
            )
            .subscribe(([ message, user ]) => this.updateUserIsTyping(user, !!message));
```

with this code it will emit immediately for the first *two* times that the user starts typing and starts throttling it then, and if you time it right, you will not get an emission when the user clears the input.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach:

```js
const input$ = this.chatForm.get('message').valuesChanges;
const emptyInput$ = input$.pipe(filter(v => !v));

const src$ = input$.pipe(
  observeOn(asyncScheduler),
  throttle(() => timer(1000).pipe(takeUntil(emptyInput$))),
  /* ... */
).subscribe(/* ... */)
```

- if the user is continuously typing, a single value per 1000ms will be emitted
- if the user empties the input, `emptyInput$` will emit, meaning that the `throttle`'s inner observable will complete.

`observeOn(asyncScheduler)` is used because the `valuesChanges` Subject has 2 subscribers(`input$.pipe(...)` and the one from `takeUntil`) and we want to make sure that the `throttle`'s inner obs. is completed **before** the empty value is passed along.

Without doing this, the empty value will arrive while the **throttling is still happening**(the observable is still active) and it wouldn't be emitted, since `throttle` has `leading: true` and `trailing: false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to do it by creating two streams and merging them like this:

```js
        const stream1 = this.chatForm.get('message')
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(
                throttleTime(1000)
            );

        const stream2 = this.chatForm.get('message')
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(
                startWith(this.chatForm.get('message').value),
                pairwise(),
                flatMap(pair => {
                    return pair.every(x => x) ? EMPTY : of(pair[1]);
                })
            );

        merge(stream1, stream2)
            .pipe(
                // when both streams emit at the same time we only want one result
                debounceTime(0),
                withLatestFrom(this.user$)
            )
            .subscribe(([ message, user ]) => this.updateUserIsTyping(user, !!message))
```

I'm still curious to learn if there's a single stream solution though